# How to implement JQuery Selector for assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, selectors-api

Javascript's `document.querySelectorAll(*cssSelector*)` returns  a `NodeList` of matching element n. (Is this different from an array of element objects?).

So if I want to implement a function that assigns style properties to each of those array elements, in the way `jQuery` does so, I assume I need an extension method on `document`. But such a function would have to return more than one value, and `'yield'` to the rest of the calling chain each time. How do I accomplish that?

This is what I have so far ([CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/patrickgomes/pen/gGQaQV)): The logic is obviously faulty at some point:

```
function doThis() { //called by any trigger
    document.$("p").style.color = "red"; //should change all 'p's fore color to red.
}

document.$ = function(cssSel) {   //extension method
    var elsSelected =  countElements(cssSel) // Generator
    for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(cssSel).length; i++) {
        return elsSelected.next().value;
    }
}

function* countElements (cssSel) {
    elList = document.querySelectorAll(cssSel);
    for (var i = 0; i < elList.length; i++) {
        yield elList[i];
    }
}
```

I would also like to use `$` without saying `document.$.`  Adding `prototype` between `document` and $ in the extension method declaration didn't help.

Comment: @Lixus No, with jQuery one doesn't need to interate over the collection. You can simply say ` $("p").css("background-color", "red");` to change all p's background-color property, for instance.

Comment: True that, I stand corrected